# Gson doesn't parse an exposed field

Tags: java, json, hibernate, gson

I have the following *POJO*'s:

```
public class Prices implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Expose private Integer idPrice;
    @Expose private String date;
    @Expose private Double price;
    @Expose private OrderLine orderLine;

    public Prices(){}
    // getters and setters
}

public class OrderLine implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Expose private Integer idOrderLine;
    @Expose private Articles art;
    @Expose private Integer q;

    private List<Prices> prices;

    public OrderLine(){}
    // getters and setters  
}
```

I'm trying to parse a price object to *JSON* by using the following method:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
String response = gson.toJson(price);
```

... but somehow *GSON* doesn't parse the `OrderLine` contained in the `Price` object.
If i do:

```
 System.out.println("Price: " + response);
```

I get the following answer:

```
Price: {"idPrice":1,"date":"2014-08-24","price":37.0,"orderLine":{}}
```

I'm using *Hibernate* too but I don't think it is the problem because if I do:

```
System.out.println(price);
```

... then I get the whole object data.

What am I doing wrong ?

**Update:**

This is how i initialize my price variable. (must say i'm new to Hibernate and Gson)

```
public static String getPrice(Integer idPrice) {

  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

  String hql = "from Prices p where p.idPrice = :idPrice";

  Prices price = (Prices) session.createQuery(hql)
                  .setParameter("idPrice", idPrice)
                  .uniqueResult();

  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
  String response = gson.toJson(price);


  // i have added the following code just to see what results i was getting
  System.out.println(price); <--- this shows all the object's data
  System.out.println(response); <-- this shows Price: {"idPrice":1,"date":"2014-08-   24","price":37.0,"orderLine":{}}


  tx.commit();
  session.flush();
  session.close();

  return response;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us how you initialise your `price` variable? Are you sure that you're correctly setting its `orderLine`?

Comment: i've added an update

Comment: By `this shows all the objects's data`, you mean something like
`{"idPrice":1,"date":"2014-08-24","price":37.0,"orderLine":{"idOrderLine":123,"q":456}}`? I believe that your `price` object actually isn't properly populated. Maybe your query need to `join` on the OrderList table or something. I'd suggest you to use a debugger to see whether your `price` object actually has its `orderLine` set as you expect.

Comment: thanks, now i know where to look. as soon as i find the solution i will post it.