# converting java DTO list into JSON object

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, gson

I have a DTO class like this:

```
package stbet.model.dto.db;

public class UKDashboardEventDTO implements Serializable{

private Long eventId;
private String meetingCode;
private String meetingName;
private String eventTime;
private String eventCode;
private String settleStatus;
private String category;

//getters and setters here:

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "eventList{" + "eventId=" + eventId + ", meetingCode=" + meetingCode + ", meetingName=" + meetingName
            + "eventTime=" + eventTime + ", eventCode=" + eventCode + ", settleStatus=" + settleStatus
            + ", category=" + category + '}';
}

}
```

and I do some query stuff and create a java List of above DTO type.

```
                   for(Event ev : eventList){
                        dto = new UKDashboardEventDTO();
                        // some stuff
                        dto.setEventCode(ev.getEventCode());
                        dto.setEventId(ev.getId());
                        dto.setEventTime(ev.getEventTime());
                        dto.setMeetingName(ev.getMeeting().getMeetingName());
                        dto.setMeetingCode(ev.getMeeting().getMeetingCode());

                        eventDTOList.add(dto);    
                    }
```

Then I add this list into a Hashmap and covert it into a JSON object like this:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("eventList",eventDTOList);
```

now convert into the json:

```
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("eventMap", map);

        } catch (JSONException ex) {
        }
        out.println(obj);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

but when I get this object from client side, I am getting the dto package/object names list when parse or stringify the output instead of the proper dto values I passed from Java. What I get is this:

```
"{"eventMap":{"eventList":["stbet.model.dto.db.UKDashboardEventDTO@617538bb","stbet.model.dto.db.UKDashboardEventDTO@56dfaef9","stbet.model.dto.db.UKDashboardEventDTO@775889fd","stbet.model.dto.db.UKDashboardEventDTO@55cb7e41","stbet.model.dto.db.UKDashboardEventDTO@22ce0968","stbet.model.dto.db.UKDashboardEventDTO@4cb9cb2"]}}"
```

can you please let me know how to get the dto values I set from Java to client side json without java package name as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could fix it with your suggestions @Trynkiewicz Mariusz and @Paul John.
What I did was:
1. remove @Expose annotation
2. overridden the toString(){...} method.
3. remove the map implementation and used a List.
4. used gson.toJson(eventList);

this solved the issue and the output now is like :

[{
      "eventId":167804,
      "meetingCode":"V5PGB",
      "meetingName":"SprintValley",
      "eventTime":"15:38:00",
      "eventCode":"10:08:00",
      "category":"HR"
   },
   {
      "eventId":167805,
      "meetingCode":"V5PGB",
      "meetingName":"SprintValley",
      "eventTime":"15:50:00",
      "eventCode":"10:20:00",
      "category":"HR"
   },..]

Thanks again guys...

Answer (score 1):

You should Override the toString field on the DTO, to print out all the individual field values.
This toString will be called when you do out.println(obj);

eg.

```
toString() {
 // this method should list out all the attributes.
 }
```

You should be using GSONBuilder to create the gson. Examples: 
[Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations)

[Gson doesn't parse an exposed field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476712/gson-doesnt-parse-an-exposed-field)

Here is a post on using GSON also

[How to expose a method using GSon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416276/how-to-expose-a-method-using-gson)

Comment: Thanks, that is also a good point but it alone did not solve the issue.

Comment: hi Paul, I could be able to fix it. Pls have a look at my answer. thanks for your support bro !

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're using both JSON and GSON libraries, `JSONException` exists in JSON one and `Expose` annotation is in GSON. Please make sure you don't mix them as I won't work as intended.

Secondly, from [Expose](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) documentation

> An annotation that indicates this member should be exposed for JSON serialization or deserialization.
>
> This annotation has no effect unless you build Gson with a GsonBuilder and invoke [GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()) method.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried without using @Expose also but getting the same output :(

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva have you tried using [GsonBuilder](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html)?

Comment: I tried gson.toJson(map); but getting same output. I will try the GsonBuilder() as well. thanks